Connecting to a Postgres DB on an AWS EC2 instance remotely
I want to use python and connect to an SQL DB on an AWS EC2 instance (Running on Windows OS). But I am not able to able to establish the connection. I keep getting an error
Error: connection to server at "IP_ADDRESS", port 5432 failed: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060)
    Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?

This is the way I try to make the connection remotely
import psycopg2

conn_str = f"host='{host}' dbname='{database}' user='{user}' password='{password}'"

try:
    # Connect to PostgreSQL
    conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_str)

    # SQL Query
    #sql_query = 'SELECT * FROM table' 


    # Close connection
    conn.close()

except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error: {e}")

Here, for host I use the Public IP Address of my EC2 instance. When I try running the same on the local machine using localhost as the host, it works.
Upon research, I found that I need to make changes to my pg_hbaf.conf file which I have done and this is how the file looks now.
IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5 

Also, kept listen_addresses = '*' in my postgresql.conf file as well.
In addition, in AWS, I have also added inbound rules to all my existing security groups as well to include PostgreSQL as port 5432 under TCP for any IPv4 address.

I am still not able to establish a connection from my system to the postgreSQL server. Is there something I have done wrong or do I need to do in addition?

A timeout is normally caused by a Security Group blocking the connection, but your configuration seems correct. Can you possibly try connecting to PostgreSQL from the Windows EC2 instance? That way, it will test the database rather than the network. First, try connecting to postgres on localhost, then try on the private IP address of the instance, then try the public IP address of the instance. Depending on where it fails amongst those 3 should give you a hint as to where something needs a different configuration.

Ok, I was able to solve the issue. Letting people know what worked for me in case someone else faces the same problem in the future.
The Windows Firewall in the instance was blocking the connection. So, I had to create a new rule to allow access to Port 5432.
This can be done by going to
1. Control Panel =>> System and Security
2. Then go to Windows Firewall and choose Advanced Settings
3. Then create a new inbound rule to allow connection to Port 5432
Attaching a link to the solution (Check out the solution from user17476)
Solution with Image Guide
Here, the solution was creating an inbound rule for postgresql program. But the steps are similar to create a rule to allow Port access as well.
